# Weird rendering for flip animation in iOS7 and Safari 7

Tags: html, css, animation, safari

I'm building a web-based publication that uses a simple CSS animation. It's a circle with a title that starts from the 'back' then plays through till it shows its 'front' when the page is loaded. The animation plays through fine on Chrome and Safari 6 but when testing on a device the circle disappears and there's weird flickering and whitespace over the hero image it overlaps.

I'm unable to provide a web preview to share with you guys, nor a gif of the problem (sorry!), but let me know if I need to give out more information.

EDIT: Managed to 'solve' the rendering issue but it flickers when rotating over the image. Any ideas?

Image of the page I'm trying to create:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsxpZ.jpg

The HTML Structure:

```
<div class="circle-feat flip-circle">
    <div class="circle-title">
        <h1 class="book-align-center Title-White" data-name="title">COLD IN JULY</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Snippet of the CSS:

```
.circle-feat {
  position: relative;
  width: 84%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 42% 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  z-index: 10;
}

.circle-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.circle-title:before {
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle-title h1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.flip-circle {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: flip;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800) translateZ(0) rotateY(-180deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(800) translateZ(0) rotateY(0deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an avid Apple user (sorry if this is irrelevant), but I think your problem might have something to do with the prefixes.  The new versions of Safari do not need the -webkit- prefix in the transform, but some older versions do...  You might try adding all prefixes to the transforms and transitions and see if it works any better.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to improve the issue either. I think it might be something related to the circle/shape - applying the animation to text (i.e. .circle-title) seems to play through fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok so after a little investigating, I had to remove the background-color rule attached to the article. I guess Safari iOS7 just couldn't handle it - is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I should really put this in an answer since this, for the most part, answers my own question. I managed to solve the rendering issue by removing the background-color rule attached to the article, I guess Safari iOS7 just couldn't cope with it in there.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the problem could be caused only by the iPhone you are using (lack of RAM, too many apps, or perhaps browser configurations).  You might try using a friend's iOS7 device and check whether or not this is the case.

In my experience mobile devices don't handle CSS3 animations very well on the web, and perhaps Apple has cut some corners in iOS7.  Due to this, you might try creating a mobile version of this publication that doesn't have any complex animations in it.  [This article on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) is great - it shows how to detect a device's size in real time a apply separate style sheets using jQuery or pure Javascript.  I know this isn't really a *solution*, but if removing the background-colour from the animation makes it look bad, this might be your only option.  Let me know if any of this fixes it!

Comment: I'm actually testing this on an iPad Mini Retina 2 and the issue crops up in the web preview too. Although only in Safari 7, I've tested it on Safari 6 and it plays through fine. I'll keep looking for a solution though and let you know if I find anything!

Comment: Ok found another solution. I had to add:  `transform: translateZ(1000px); transform-style: preserve-3d;`  to the parent of the rotating element so that safari thinks it's 1000px in front of the image!